Can I enter South Korea with 2 different passports (in separate times)
I've entered South Korea with passport A in the past, but want to know if I can enter again with Passport B?

In principle nothing stops you from doing that but why do you ask? Is it more convenient because you only have one of your passports at hand? Have you changed citizenship in the meantime? Are you trying to stay longer in Korea? Are you concerned about the passport you are using to leave another country before entering Korea? Depending on the answer, there may be other solutions or other issues to consider than the passport you are using to enter Korea.

I have entered the same country on two different passports simply because I forgot the "preferred" one at home.

Just that I am renewing one and need to give it in for processing. so meanwhile if I travel i need to use my 2nd passport. thanks!

Yes, you can IF you can meet the entry requirements (K-eTA, Visa, etc.) imposed on holders of Passport B. Note: meeting the requirements with one passport does not waive the requirements on the other. You may need a new visa or K-eTA for passport B even if you have one for passport A.

And if there are any limits in terms of number of days per period they cumulate, they are not counted separately.

Not necessarily for Korea. If Passport B is Canadian, the traveler could obtain six months upon entry even if that exceeds what they received under Passport A.

I'm going only for few days and am aware need to register K-eta! Good to know I should be able to enter with my 2nd passport, thanks!
